# Rapid SSL private key in to setup https with my apache sever

Tags: apache, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, private-key

I bought **SSL certificate** to apply it to my site which is hosted in **Digitalocean  VPS**,

When I bought SSL , Rapid SSL emailed the keys with that email.

In that mail they mentioned

**public.crt** and **intermediate.crt** but they did not provide me any **private.key.**

But in their installation guide they wrote like this

```
           SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/public.crt  
           This will need to point to the your SSL certificate itself that we issued to you

           SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/private/private.key 
           This will need to point to the private key file associated with your certificate.

           SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/intermediate.crt  
           This will need to point to the the intermediate file
```

Now how can I get this **private.key** file

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have started with a private key of your own. The process goes like this:

1. You create a keypair.
2. You create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) which wraps the public key.
3. You submit the CSR.
4. They sign it and send back the signed certificate and their own certificate chain.

You couldn't have got to first base without a private key.